# How to Open and Save Files in Parallel Directory Without Knowing Full Path

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is an easy way to access 'parallel' directories (See photo for what I am talking about... I don't know what else to call them, please correct me if they are called something else!) from a Python file without having to input the string path.

The basic structure I intend to use is shown in  the picture. The structure will be used across different computers, so I need to avoid just typing in `"C:\stuff_to_get_there\parent_directory\data\file.txt"` because `"C:\stuff_to_get_there"` will not be the same on different computers.

I want to store the `.py` files in their own directory, then access the data files in `data` directory, and save figures to `figures` directory. I was thinking of trying `os` module but not sure if that's the correct way to go.

```
parent directory
    scripts
        .py files
    
    figures
        save files here

    data
        .txt files stored here
```

[image: Desired file pathing behavior. Scripts stored in one directory, and each script can access data from a different directory at the same level, and save to a figures directory at the same level.]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It sounds like you might want to read up on [relative paths](https://networkencyclopedia.com/relative-path/).

Comment: `siblings`. You can use `../figures` to go up one level and then back down.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thank you. Can't believe I missed that